# Visual Studio Community Edition can't access VSTS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I'm working on a .NET project with a subcontractor.
The client has all source code in Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS).

The client has granted access to the subcontractor, but he cannot see any source code or builds.
When logging in to the VSTS website, he receives the following error messages:

"TF400409: You do not have licensing rights to access this feature: Code"
"We could not verify your Visual Studio subscription so we've downgraded you to Stakeholder."

The subcontractor meets the criteria for commercial development using the Community Edition of Visual Studio (fewer than 5 developers etc.), so it would be sad if they had to purchase a license, just to access one client's source code.

Is there a way out?
Could he maybe set up a free VSTS "Community" instance and thus be marked as "licensed" in the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access level is assigned per Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) subscription and not per company. So even though you contractor might be considered a single entity he will be part of the free license count for the particular subscription he is trying to access. Either there are already 5 free developers or he is not assigned the correct level.

Access level is assigned through the dashboard https://{youraccount}.visualstudio.com (select Users from the '...' menu). The 5 free licenses can be used by assigning the users to the *Basic* access level. You can read more here: [Manage users and access in VSTS (if you turned off User Hub)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/add-account-users-assign-access-levels).

Comment: Where would we able to see that? In fact, the client does not have a single developer of their own. The subcontractors and I are the only active developers on the project. They do have some project managers/administrators though. Also, they used to have other developers, before we came in. Maybe we could just throw out the unused accounts?

Comment: Hmm, then maybe your customer have registered you wrong in the VSTS dashboard. They need to register you with the Basic assess level, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/add-account-users-assign-access-levels.

Comment: Indeed the client had registered the subcontractor as a subscriber because they assumed he would have a license of his own anyway and didn't want to "waste" any of their 5 "free" basic licenses. Thank you!

Comment: Super - I will add to the answer to cover this too.